# WSO2 BAM 2.5 - Output Event Adaptor

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, wso2-cep, wso2-bam

Two questions on WSO2 BAM 2.5 Output Event Adaptor - 1) Why is there no "email" option in the output event adaptor type? As per the documentation, it should be there. Even if I create my own XML file for the Email event adaptor and drop it in the required folder, then type "email" is not recognized and the BAM is showing that as "inactive". 2) Which directory and file does the default logger output event adaptor write the logs to? I have configured that and I can see that the messages have got generated through Hive scripts and written to BAMNotifications column family but I am not able to see the logs in the repository/logs directory log files? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) This issue occurred because of an OSGI loading issue in soap output adapter (It causes failure to some other output adapters). We have fixed that in next BAM version. For the moment to overcome this issue, please remove the soap output adapter jar (from plugins directory), restart and continue.

2) It needs to go to wso2carbon.log file. Can you please verify the log4j properties.

Comment: 1) The solution worked. Now I can see the different output event adaptors. Thanks. 2) I checked the log4j properties and it does point to wso2carbon.log file but I don't see any logs from the output event adaptor. I will open another threrad to discuss just point 2 and accept the answer since 1 is now resolved